# Power Query - How to pass blank Excel cell as NULL value?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have SQL that looks like this, which works fine in SSMS:

```
    DECLARE @pPart  VARCHAR(100)    =   '00039',    
            @pColor VARCHAR(100)    =   '01816'         

    SET     @pPart   = ISNULL(@pPart,'-1')          
    SET     @pColor  = ISNULL(@pColor,'-1')         

    SELECT  *
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   (PartID  IN (SELECT (@pPart))  OR @pPart  = '-1')
    AND     (ColorID IN (SELECT (@pColor)) OR @pColor = '-1')
```

If I change either value (or both values) in the DECLARE from a value to NULL, the code returns the results I expect. I'm just not sure how to make this work within Power Query. If both cells are populated with values, the query works. If I delete the value from either cell, it's just returning a list of all the tables in my database (weird...).

I created a named range called "GetValues" that covers B2:B3 and looks like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Part | 00039 |
| Color | 01816 |

In the Advanced Editor of Power Query, my query looks like this:

```
let
    Source  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GetValues"]}[Content],
    pPart   = Source{1}[Column1],
    pColor  = Source{2}[Column1],
    Query   = "

    DECLARE @pPart  VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pPart &"',  
            @pColor VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pColor &"'          

    SET     @pPart  = ISNULL(@pPart,'-1')           
    SET     @pColor = ISNULL(@pColor,'-1')          

    SELECT  *
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   (PartID  IN (SELECT (@pPart))  OR @pPart  = '-1')
    AND     (ColorID IN (SELECT (@pColor)) OR @pColor = '-1')
    ",

    Target = Sql.Database("myServer", "myDatabase", [Query=Query])
in
    Target
```

I tried changing my SET lines, which also works in SSMS if I change a value to '' or ' ' but still returns a list of all tables in my DB in Power Query. I'm trimming the strings in case the user put a space in the cells instead of leaving them blank:

```
    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@pPart))  = '' SET @pPart  = '-1' 
    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@pColor)) = '' SET @pColor = '-1'
```

So how do I pass a blank cell as NULL or at least as '' ?

EDIT: I also tried stripping my query down to the bare bones to see what parameters are being passed. This query successfully returns the value in B2.

```
let
    Source  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GetValues"]}[Content],
    pPart   = Source{1}[Column1],
    Query   = "

    DECLARE @pPart  VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pPart &"'   
    SELECT  @pPart

    ",

    Target = Sql.Database("myServer", "myDatabase", [Query=Query])
in
    Target
```

Now I want to see what happens when I include the blank cell B3:

```
let
    Source  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GetValues"]}[Content],
    pPart   = Source{1}[Column1],
    pColor  = Source{2}[Column1],
    Query   = "

    DECLARE @pPart  VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pPart &"',  
            @pColor VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pColor &"'          
    SELECT  @pPart, @pColor

    ",

    Target = Sql.Database("myServer", "myDatabase", [Query=Query])
in
    Target
```

This query also returned a list of all the tables in my database.

I also tried changing

```
in
    Target
```

to

```
in
    pColor
```

and the query preview shows `null` in all lowercase, which makes me think it's indeed returning a null value. I just can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Concatenating with `null` yields `null`, much like in SQL. `Query` ends up `null`, meaning the `Sql.Database` call simply does what it normally does when not given a query and spits out the list of tables. Try something like `"... @pColor VARCHAR(100) = " & (if pColor = null then "NULL" else "'" & pColor & "'")` to treat `null` as `NULL`. (This is still "wrong" in that it breaks if `pColor` contains an apostrophe, fixing that is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: When you start with pPart or  pColor  of null, what results are you expecting?

Comment: When pPart is null, return all pParts and pColor for the pColor that's selected. If pColor is null, return the pPart and all pColors for the pPart that's selected. In other words, null should be treated as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to treat blank cell values as a wildcard then this will work: first remove the SET statements then use this sql:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   (PartID  = @pPart OR @pPart  is null OR TRIM(@pPart) ='')
    AND     (ColorID = @pColor OR @pColor is null OR TRIM(@pColor) ='')
```

You would get:

- Alll rows only if both variables are blank.
- No rows if @pPart is not null/blank and has no matches
- No rows if @pColor is not null/blank and has no matches

You could add this condition to prevent returning any rows when both inputs are blank/ null:

```
AND ( ISNULL(TRIM(pPart), '') <> '' OR  ISNULL(TRIM(pColor), '') <> '')
```

Comment: I removed the 2 SET statements and used your WHERE clause, but unfortunately it's still returning a list of tables when 1 of the 2  (or both) cells in Excel is blank. It works fine if both cells are populated.

Comment: It seems like if at least one of the Excel cells is blank, the actual query is ignored. I tried doing `SELECT ISNULL(@pPart, 0), ISNULL(@pColor, 0)` and it still returned the list of tables.

Comment: This might help? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-parameter-query-power-query-5eb365bc-3982-4ab2-8830-b205a69e0f33

Comment: adding the `@pPart is null` made sense from a SQL perspective, but Power Query can't seem to pass a null value from a parameter down to the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I had to address the null values before the query started. For whatever reason (EDIT: Jeroen gives the actual reason in the comment below), passing pPart or pColor as NULL would just return a list of tables and didn't actually pass the NULL value. Here's what seems to be working:

```
let
    Source  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GetValues"]}[Content],
    pPart   = if Source{1}[Column1] = null then "-1" else Source{1}[Column1],
    pColor  = if Source{2}[Column1] = null then "-1" else Source{2}[Column1],
    Query   = "

    DECLARE @pPart  VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pPart &"',  
            @pColor VARCHAR(100)    =   '"& pColor &"'          

    SELECT  *
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   (PartID= '" & pPart & "' OR " & pPart & " = '-1')
    AND     (ColorID = '" & pColor & "' OR " & pColor & " = '-1')
    ",

    Target = Sql.Database("myServer", "myDatabase", [Query=Query])
in
    Target
```

Comment: It's not "for whatever reason", it's because `null & "a value"` yields `null`, just as `NULL + 'A'` yields `NULL` in SQL. M uses the same "`null` is unknown" logic as SQL. No value is being passed here, you're just concatenating strings. M has no problem passing `null` values as parameters to functions, but that's not what's happening here.